# load https site from a frame

Tags: html, frame

consider this:

```
<html>
<frameset cols="50%,50%" frameborder=no border=no framespacing=no>
<frame src="http://site1.com">
<frame src="https://site2.com">
</frameset>
</html>
```

I've saved this file into `myCompareFrames.html` and trying to open it with `google-chrome`.

the reason for this was to have two frames next to each other so I can compare some results (instead of having two pages open LOL)

however it only opens the `http` and **NOT** `https` (note: none of the sites are local)

So my questions are:

- why can it load a http and not a https?
- Is there an easy way of this way?

**NOTE:**

If no easy way of doing this, I'll be happy with the explanation of why this would happen as I'm so curious  but I'm not going to spend hours on silly problem like this.

Comment: if it's a security restriction, there should be something mentioned about it in your browser's console.

Comment: You can't load resources from https inside a http protocol, it's a security restriction. It works equal in AJAX calls, scripts and css includes, etc.  Your solution is to visit in protocol https the page with the frameset and load all in the same protocol.

Comment: you are using an iframe change "<frame>" to "<iframe>"



<html>
    <frameset cols="50%,50%" frameborder=no border=no framespacing=no>
    <iframe src="http://site1.com">
    <iframe src="https://site2.com">
    </frameset>
    </html>

Comment: thx guys, I thought it might be for security and yet, I don't know how that could be a security issue...

Answer (score 0):

For a local file

```
<html>
<frameset cols="50%,50%" frameborder=no border=no framespacing=no>
  <frame src="http://spiegel.de">
  <frame src="https://www.wikipedia.org">
</frameset>
</html>
```

Firefox developer edition loaded both pages.

Yet, there were problems when using `stackoverflow.com` instead of `spiegel.de`, for example.

So, it might be site-dependent. As a guess, it might be that the https elements, which certainly exist for SO, caused the load to fail, in combination with [mixed-content protection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent) (which exists for IE and Chrome, as well). The web console showed no errors.

As for why it is a security problem, see f.ex. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38317/specific-risks-of-embedding-an-https-iframe-in-an-http-page